# Statistical Treatment of Classical Field Theories

Tags: statistical-mechanics, classical-field-theory

Is there a conceptual problem in formulating of Liouville's theorem and the BBGKY Hierarchy for classical field theories? I always see treatments of Lioville's theorem only in the context of classical mechanics. I also know that most references treat linear response theory only for classical mechanics and do not touch upon linear response theory aspects of classical field theories such as Kubo formula.

One can definitely take the continuum limit of a classical mechanical system and obtain some sort of Lioville's theorem or BBGKY hierarchy for the continuum field theory. I would like see if this is discussed in some rigorous way in any reference. In particular, I'm looking for references which discuss aspects such as the phase space for classical field theories, BBGKY and Green-Kubo Formula. I'm not a mathematician so a good systematic treatment I'm comfortable with for classical mechanics is [David Tong's lecture notes](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/kintheory/) and the text by [Evans and Moriss](https://www.google.com/search?gs_ssp=eJzj4tFP1zc0SsotKMouMjFg9NIvLkksySwuyUxOzFHITU3OSMzLTC5WyE9TyMvPSy0szczJTCrKLM1VyMkEclKKAcLSFz4&q=statistical%20mechanics%20of%20nonequilibrium%20liquids&oq=STATISTICAL%20MECHANICS%20OF%20NONEQUILIBRIUM%20LIQUIDS&aqs=chrome.1.0i355i512j46i512j69i64j0i22i30j0i390i650l4.3638j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). I'm looking for similar treatments for classical field theories.

Comment: We know that there is ultimately a problem with classical fields. The equipartition theorem implies that energy moves to the UV, and we encounter the Rayleigh-Jeans catastrophe.

Comment: Have you read Statistical Mechanics by McQuarrie? This book I think will contain what you need, and doesn't assume that much math background. I think it's available on the internet archive as a pdf as well. In particular, I think Chapters 7 and 18 will be interesting for you, which will discuss the Liouville equation and the BBGKY hierarchy in the context of the kinetic theory of gasses. There is also some more modern work on the topic that I could point you to if you're interested, but this should be a good starting point.

Comment: @ZinnTheJackal, I'm aware of McQuarrie's book. As I mentioned in my question, I'm comfortable with Liouville equation and BBGKY heirarchy in the context of classical mechanics and I'm looking for texts which discuss these equations in the classical field theory context. What are the modern works you are taking about? Do any of these works discuss the long time tails in the correlation functions?

Comment: @physicscircus My apologies, I read your question and bit too quickly this morning and I realize I misunderstood - I don't think what I have in mind is relevant. Good luck finding an answer!

Comment: If you would like to understand hydrodynamic tails, the you should look at texts on stochastic field theories (these are not quite classical field theories, they are coarse grained hydrodynamic theories). See, for example, Mazenko, Nonequilibrium Statistical Mechanics, or Cardy, Scaling and Renormalization, and Tauber, Critical Dynamics.